# discord.py - Separate Updatable Tabs

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Im trying to divide the python console into tabs so at the top it shows the time that updates every second for example and at the bottom the bot logs like messages sent by the users.

Heres an example

```
---------------------------
| Date : 16 Jul 2019   # These are the values that
| Time : 4:27pm        # update every second
---------------------------
Neon#6352 : Hello      # Messages sent by the users
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you would have to create tabs. If you want to update time, you can use the [datetime library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) strings. To get the messages you would have to do this: (written in rewrite)

```py
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your_prefix")

    @bot.listen()
    async def on_message():
        user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=message.author.id)
        print(f"{user}: {message.content}")
```

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Thanks for edit, blackbrandt! I don't know how could I forget about indents :P

Comment: Not exactly I was trying to acheve

Comment: Well, that's what I'v read from your question. This what I'v sent is the only thing connected with d.py. Other things like tabs are just `print()` and not d.py...